# Breeze query not fetching records that checks for date columns in sql server table

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, breeze

```
var shippedFromDt = new Date(2013, 09, 09);
var query = EntityQuery.from('Shipments')
            .where(breeze.Predicate.create("ShipmentDate", ">=", shippedFromDt))
            .orderByDesc("ID")
```

I have records in table where the Shipment date is '10/9/2013'. But when I run above query, I do not get any records. If I change the date to '10/8/2013', the query returns me the records. I am also using ">=" query operator & so the query should return me the data when the input date is '10/9/2013'. I am not sure if this is happening because the shippedFromDt includes time information also where as the table column only stores date. I tried creating the Date object by passing 0 values for hours,min & seconds parameters but this does not help.

Javascript month index starts from 0, hence 09 is used for October.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely a timezone issue. Basically any date you create on the client is defined as being in the client browser's timezone.  Dates stored on the database server, by comparison, unless they are of  DateTimeOffset or DateTime2 datatypes, are defined without any timezone specified, and thus may be considered as having a UTC Offset of 0. i.e GMT.   So your best bet is to adjust your client time by the client timezone offset to convert them into GMT times; something like this. ( I haven't checked the line below, so the sign might be off).

```
var adjustedDate = new Date(yourDate.getTime() - (yourDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
```

[A similar problem discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone)

Another approach is to define your date as a string with a "Z" specifier to indicate that you want your date to be a UTC O offset and then parse the string into a date.

A final approach is to use DateTime2 or DateTimeOffset datatypes in your database where the timezone offset for all data is the same as that on your client.

Comment: The date on client is "Wed Oct 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT - 0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) which is already in GMT, so I don't think I need to convert the client date to UTC Offset of 0. Also, I tried changing the datatype on database as datetime2 but that does not help.

Comment: Actually you do need to convert it. Your client has a 4 hour offset but the server by default, because there is no offset, effectively has a 0 hour offset.  You can't compare the times without normalizing one or the other.

Comment: Thank you, that line of code did work & now my breeze query is returning the desired records. Not sure though, why did you multiply the timezoneoffset by 60000 ? [Is it because 60000 ms = 60 sec = 1 min ?]

Comment: Yes the time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time, the getTime method needs milliseconds so minutes * 60000 === milliseconds