# JavaScript Date converting to the wrong Java Date

Tags: javascript, java

I have a JavaScript Date object,`Thu Jul 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)`, which is passed to a Java method that stores this date in a Java Date object. But the Java date object shows this date as `Wed Jul 01 23:00:00 CDT 2015`. How can I get the correct conversion from JavaScript Date to Java Date?

**Note:** This only happens when i have my PC set to Eastern Standard Time and the clock is set to around 9 AM. Other than that, if i set my PC's timezone back to Central Standard Time, then this is no longer an issue.

**Update**

The number of milliseconds from the epoch to 07/02/15 is 1435809600000. If I take these milliseconds and create a JS Date object like so, `new Date(1435809600000)`, I get this: *Thu Jul 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)*. But when i try to create a Java Date object, `new Date(1435809600000)`, I get: *Wed Jul 01 23:00:00 CDT 2015*

Comment: Add the string that you pass to java from js, and how you're formatting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to send the data as long (milliseconds from 1/1/1970) and construct a new Date in java starting from it.

Javascript code

```
var date = ... // date is of type Date
var dateMillis = date.getTime();  // Milliseconds long representing the date
```

Java code

```
long dateMillis = .... // Milliseconds long representing the date
Date date = new Date(dateMillis);
```

Comment: I thought this would work too. I updated the OP explaining the results of attempting what you suggested.

Comment: The problem is that you are using different Standard Time in java and in javascript. If you use the same it should work.

Comment: I selected this. I realized that the client is using the EST timezone, and the server is using the CST timezone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most definitely the Local TZ of the client.  Maybe this post can help, by removing the localization from your DateTime object. [How to ignore user's time zone and force Date() use specific time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
String fromJavascript = "Thu Jul 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.US);

try {
    Date converted = sdf.parse(fromJavascript);

    System.out.println(converted);
} catch (ParseException e) {            
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The *converted* object should contain the correct date. What gets printed will depend on the TZ of the running client. But that you can control when presenting.