# How to make Google chart not to convert timezone in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, timezone, google-visualization

I have my controller like this

```
$scope.myChartApp =  {
      "type": "AreaChart",
      "options": {
        'isStacked': true,
        'seriesType': 'area',
        'focusTarget': 'category',
        'legend': {
          position: 'bottom'
        },
        'vAxis': {
          format: 'short'
        },

      },
      "data": [
        [
          'Datetime',
          'RX',
          'TX'
        ],
        [
          new Date(1497273300000),
          5328362.222222222,
          37336.24888888889
        ][
          new Date(1497274200000),
          4372552.96,
          63361.00444444444
        ][
          new Date(1497275100000),
          5909441.448888889,
          70055.12
        ][
          new Date(1497276000000),
          6941783.8133333335,
          79086.50666666667
        ]
      ]
    }
```

And in my html

```
<div google-chart chart="myChartApp" style="height:300px; width:100%;"></div>
```

It converts time like this

```
[
Tue Jun 06 2017 23:00:19 GMT+0530 (IST),
5328362.222222222,
37336.24888888889
]
```

My expected graph shows times with +05.30 hours difference 
Google chart converts timezone. but don't want to convert it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this isn't related to google charts, it's due to javascript functionality -- see these answers --> [How to ignore user's time zone and force Date() use specific time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2771609/5090771) -- [Parse date without timezone javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17545708/5090771)