# Can we set default timezone for browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timezone

I have one question about the browser timezone. I notice that my system's date and time will be affected by my computer's timezone setting.

let's say I have created one data in the database

`{ item_name: 'A', created_time: '2022-06-06T06:42:12.933+0000' }`

if my timezone is **Singapore**, the time will show as `6-Jun-22 2:42 pm` in my browser

But when I change my timezone to **Fiji**, the time will show as `6-Jun-22 6:42 pm` in my browser

So, how do to prevent this issue?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone perhaps? I'd argue this might break user's expectation though

Comment: `"...the time will show as 6-Jun-22 2:42 pm in my browser"` - That depends entirely on how *you* decide to create and display it, which you didn't show any code for here.   Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you.