# Timestamp on Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics, timestamp, google-tag-manager

I need a little help to create a variable on google tag manager that takes me the timestamp of when an event is triggered.

Now I have implemented this custom javascript but it takes me as the timezone that of the country of the user who will trigger the event.
On the other hand, I would like timezone always +02.00, can someone teach me which part of the code I need to modify to have my timezone always set?

Thank you

```
function() 
{

  var now = new Date();
  var tzo = -now.getTimezoneOffset();
  var dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
  var pad = function(num) {
    var norm = Math.abs(Math.floor(num));
    return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
};
  return now.getHours()
    + ':' + pad(now.getMinutes()) 
    + ':' + pad(now.getSeconds())
    + '.' + pad(now.getMilliseconds())
    + dif + pad(tzo / 60) 
    + ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore user's time zone and force Date() use specific time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

This should be ample:

```js
function qwe() {
  var d = new Date();
  nd = new Date((d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)) + (3600000 * 2));
  var tzo = 120;
  var dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
  var pad = function (num) {
    var norm = Math.abs(Math.floor(num));
    return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
  };
  return nd.getHours()
    + ':' + pad(nd.getMinutes())
    + ':' + pad(nd.getSeconds())
    + '.' + pad(nd.getMilliseconds())
    + dif + pad(tzo / 60)
    + ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this answer to "**How to ignore user's time zone and force Date() use specific time zone**": [How to ignore user's time zone and force Date() use specific time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone)

It says:

A Date object's underlying value is actually in UTC. To prove this, notice that if you type `new Date(0)` you'll see something like: `Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`. 0 is treated as 0 in GMT, but `.toString()` method shows the local time.

Big note, UTC stands for *Universal* time code. The current time right now in 2 different places is the same UTC, but the output can be formatted differently.

**What we need here is some formatting**

```
var _date = new Date(1270544790922); 
// outputs > "Tue Apr 06 2010 02:06:30 GMT-0700 (PDT)", for me
_date.toLocaleString('fi-FI', { timeZone: 'Europe/Helsinki' });
// outputs > "6.4.2010 klo 12.06.30"
_date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Europe/Helsinki' });
// outputs > "4/6/2010, 12:06:30 PM"
```

This works but.... you can't really use any of the other date methods for your purposes since they describe the user's timezone. What you want is a date object that's related to the Helsinki timezone. Your options at this point are to use some 3rd party library (I recommend this), or hack-up the date object so you can use most of it's methods.

**Option 1 - a 3rd party like moment-timezone**

```
moment(1270544790922).tz('Europe/Helsinki').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
// outputs > 2010-04-06 12:06:30
moment(1270544790922).tz('Europe/Helsinki').hour()
// outputs > 12
```

This looks a lot more elegant than what we're about to do next.

**Option 2 - Hack up the date object**

```
var currentHelsinkiHoursOffset = 2; // sometimes it is 3
var date = new Date(1270544790922);
var helsenkiOffset = currentHelsinkiHoursOffset*60*60000;
var userOffset = _date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000; // [min*60000 = ms]
var helsenkiTime = new Date(date.getTime()+ helsenkiOffset + userOffset);
// Outputs > Tue Apr 06 2010 12:06:30 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

It still thinks it's GMT-0700 (PDT), but if you don't stare too hard you may be able to mistake that for a date object that's useful for your purposes.

I conveniently skipped a part. You need to be able to define `currentHelsinkiOffset`. If you can use `date.getTimezoneOffset()` on the server side, or just use some if statements to describe when the time zone changes will occur, that should solve your problem.

**Conclusion** - I think especially for this purpose you should use a date library like [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).